# Disabled Angular anchor link is clickable in microsoft edge browser

Tags: html, angularjs, microsoft-edge

I have written the below angular code for anchor link tag

```
<div class="Import">
   <a ng-disabled="List.length==0" ng-click="Click()"><i class="icon-table"></i>Import</a>
</div>
```

if the anchor tag is disabled and when try to click it is not clickable in other browsers such as chrome,firefox
but in microsoft edge browser it is clickable. Can anyone suggest how to make it as non clickable
in edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, may you need to write something like this:

```js
<div class="Import">
   <a class="btn" ng-disabled="List.length==0" ng-click="Click()"><i class="icon-table"></i>Import</a>
</div>
```

add class="btn" into the anchor hyperlink

Answer (score -2):

What do you think saying other browsers?
BTW you've unclosed correctly  tag.

Comment: This is not an answer. And there are no unclosed tags in the OP's code.